# Rust rayon tcp blocking

Tags: multithreading, rust, rayon

I'm writing a program which executes a command on server using ssh and gets the output.

The part I don't understand is lower in the code.

If the function waits and then returns a string, it works as expected, but if work with TCP it starts performing very bad. I expect that using 100 threads on 100 hosts will perform 100 times faster,
because will open 100 sockets simultaneously.

In the sleep version, changing `poolThreads` directly affects the time of execution. In the version with TCP streams, changing `pool` from 1 to 100 with 100 hosts only speeds it up from 90 to 67 because some hosts are offline.

I read the documentation, but cannot find anything to help me.

```
use clap::{App, Arg};
use rayon::prelude::*;
use rayon::ThreadPoolBuilder;
use ssh2::Session;
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::{BufReader, Read};
use std::net::{TcpStream, ToSocketAddrs};
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;

fn process_host<A>(hostname: A) -> Result<String, String>
where
    A: ToSocketAddrs + Display,
{
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    return Ok(hostname.to_string());
    // here is the problem
    // -----------------------------------------------------------
    let tcp = match TcpStream::connect(&hostname) {
        Ok(a) => a,
        Err(e) => {
            return Err(format!("{}:{}", hostname, e).to_string());
        }
    };
    let mut sess = match Session::new() {
        Ok(a) => a,
        Err(e) => {
            // todo logging
            return Err(format!("{}:{}", hostname, e).to_string());
        }
    };
    sess.set_tcp_stream(tcp);
    match sess.handshake() {
        Ok(a) => a,
        Err(e) => {
            return Err(format!("{}:{}", hostname, e).to_string());
        }
    };
    Ok(format!("{}", hostname))
}


fn main() {

    let hosts = vec!["aaaaa:22", "bbbbbbb:22"];
    let pool = ThreadPoolBuilder::new()
        .num_threads(10)
        .build()
        .expect("failed creating pool");
    pool.install(|| {
        hosts
            .par_iter()
            .map(|x| process_host(x))
            .for_each(|x| println!("{:?}", x))
    });
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. There are many parts present in the code that don't seem required to reproduce the problem. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to *minimally* reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, your error handling code can be greatly simplified: `let tcp = TcpStream::connect(&hostname).map_err(|e| format!("{}:{}", hostname, e))?;` Also, there's no need to `.to_string()` the result of `format!`, it's already a `String`.

Comment: @Shepmaster rewrited to simplify code

Comment: @Shepmaster I just don't know, how to make mre for io specific code, because thread wait performs in different way, than I expected

Comment: You state *but if work with TCP it starts performing very bad*, can you be more explicit about what you mean? How is it performing? Why do you think it should be better? Are you running your code in release mode?

Comment: Your current code uses undefined variables: `s`.

Comment: @Shepmaster sorry, it was working. Fixed that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206022/discussion-between-vladimir-and-shepmaster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug a such a problem, you need to analysis, where your program wastes its time.
There're to ways:
profiling and analyzing of TCP connections.
I suggest you 2 way, cause it's much easier.
Dump traffic with wireshark, filter it by port 22.
After this, use [conversations](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatConversations.html)
tab. Here you can sort connections by time, and can see, that program doesn't speedup because of no time limit for ssh connection.